# Does the Raspberry Pi 2 support 64-bit integers?

Tags: pi-2

I am writing a program in Python and will have a numpy array that might need to be of dtype=np.int64. Will the raspberry pi 2 be able to handle these 64 bit integers?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "integer".

If we're talking about the register size in the processor, then no, the RPi has a 32bit CPU.

If we're talking about the size of numbers it can process in Python, then yes it does.  Python has big number libraries built in.  Because of this, you can store and manipulate as big of a number as you want and have the RAM space for.  Your efficiency won't be nearly as good, but it is workable.